# Why need to escape dollar($) for automatic variable in gmake prerequiste?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have following gmake target:

```
$(GCH_demo): $(PCH_demo) | $$(@D) prebuild_demo
        @echo PCH $<
        -cp $< $(@D)
        $(CXX_demo) $(strip $(CPPFLAGS_demo) $(CXXFLAGS_demo)) -o $@ -c $<
```

Here notice the **$(@D)**:

- In prerequisite, I need to escape the dollar, so as: **$$(@D)**
- In recipe, no escape needed: :**$(@D)**

To my understanding, I want this automatic variable be expanded, so in both case, it should not be escaped - but it turns out it won't work if I don't escape the dollar in prerequisite line.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax) section from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: @devnull Yes, I have - You mean "if you really want a dollar sign in a target or prerequisite you must write two of them"? NO - I don't think I want the dollar sign, I just want it to be expanded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using secondary expansion (see the discussion in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion)).

Normally in a make rule, automatic variables are only valid *within the recipe*.  They are not available in the prerequisite list, because the targets and prerequisites of the rule are expanded before the rule is parsed; any "normal" variable reference will be expanded before make knows what the target is, and so before the automatic variable `$@` (or its alternate forms) is set.

If you enable secondary expansion, then the prerequisite list will go through a *second* round of expansion, after the rule is parsed, and in this second expansion the automatic variable `$@` will be set properly.  However, to ensure that your variable reference makes it to the second round, you have to escape it so it won't be expanded during the first round.

Consider this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
all: $(info first=$@) $$(info second=$$@)
        @:
```

When you run this you get:

```
first=
second=all
```

as expected.